# Stata error: not found in list of covariates

Tags: plot, stata

I want to plot an interaction effect among two variables.

```
margins   SentiSat_Rounded#PriceReduction
```

I get the following error:

```
'SentiSat_Rounded' not found in list of covariates
r(322);
```

The variables are present in the dataset. Also if the variable is not present in the dataset it throws a different error, like

```
variable X not found
```

Can you please suggest what is meant by not present in list of covariates?

To find covariates I came across this code:
    program covars, rclass 
        version 8

```
    capture local Covars : colnames e(b) 
    if _rc error 301 

    tempname b 
    mat `b' = e(b) 
    tokenize `Covars' 
    local k = 0 

    forval j = 1/`= colsof(`b')' {
        if "``j''" != "_cons" & `b'[1,`j'] != 0 { 
            local covars "`covars'``j'' " 
            local ++k 
        }
    }

    if `k' { 
        di as txt "{p}`covars'{p_end}" 
        return local covars "`covars'" 
        c_local covars "`covars'" 
    }   
end
```

I ran

```
covars
```

after that .. in the list of covariates, the above variable is not listed .. 
Is that list of covariates different from the variables in my dataset? How does Stata determine what is a covariate?

Comment: The `margins` command can only be used after some estimation, such as `regress`. Are you estimating first?

Comment: yes, I am estimating using xtmixed model ...

Answer (score 0):

The covariates are those used as such in the previous model. That is, `margins` always follows a modelling command, in your case `xtmixed`, and the covariates are the variables other than the response (first-named variable) named in that model call.

You may know covariates as predictors or even independent variables or through some other terminology. But for Stata covariates are certainly not just any variables in your dataset; they must have been named in your model call.

If this isn't clear to you, show us the exact `xtmixed` command preceding your `margins` call.

It shouldn't be surprising that Stata can't do anything with a variable not in the dataset!

Comment: Very nicely explained. I understood it